# Is there a way to avoid linking DCUs to a BPL?

Tags: delphi, linker, delphi-10.2-tokyo, bpl

We are using packages to split our code base into smaller pieces, but always deploy as a single monolitic executable.

When compiling the packages the units in a package project are linked together into .dcp and .bpl files and finally they are linked again into the executable (.exe).

This is is a bit of a time waster, I'd like Delphi to only compile the DCUs and not link them into packages.

So:

Is it possible to turn off linking for packages and only link in the final executable?

Comment: I don't understand why you have packages at all. It doesn't sound like you use them for anything.

Comment: Me neither. Simply make some meaningful directory structure and put the corresponding modules (units) there. To make the module naming more clear you can use namespaces.

Comment: Your post makes no sense. If you're building a single monolithic executable, there are no packages involved -- the presence of a single package means it's no longer a single monolithic executable. If you don't want packages, then don't include packages, and the .dcus are compiled directly into the executable itself. Turn off *Link with runtime packages* in the project options (Project->Options->Packages->Runtime Packages).

Comment: The source code has 300k lines of code in 2k files, would you put all of them into a single project?

Comment: I just tried to put them all into a single project and that kills the compiler with an out of memory error.

Comment: If you search around SO, you'll find that a number of people have Delphi projects with ten times your 300k lines without resorting to packages. Fewer, larger units might be less of a strain for the compiler.  Also, even in D7, System.Pas allowed for a much larger number of units at r/time: `UnitEntryTable = array [0..9999999] of PackageUnitEntry`

Comment: 300kloc is quite a small project

Comment: You also have to take third party libries into account though, which I guess it what kills the compiler. The Compiler runs into an out of memory exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fastdcc` in IDE Fix Pack from Andreas Hausladen has a switch that does exactly this:

> -x--compileonly
>
> Output intermediate files, skip linking. 1: Output only DCU and DCP.
>   2: Output only DCU.

https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/